# javascript fetch data from complex JSON

Tags: javascript

There is a json(#json) like as follow, in student section, first two one is a group, last two one is a group.(group by a set of no. like no.1 and no.2 are one set).
The problem is i need fetch the data from student section and make 2 table (depend on how many set of no., 2 in this example). How to modify the json data structure programmatically that i can fetch the data to do above thing?
The table(#table1) look like :
no. name
1   tom
2   jacky

no. name
1   tom
2   jacky

#json

```
{
"people": {
    "student": [{
        "name": "tom"
        "no.": "1"
        "other": "a"
    },{
        "name": "tom"
        "no.": "1"
        "other": "e"
    },{
        "name": "jack"
        "no.": "2"
        "other": "d"
    },{
        "name": "tom"
        "no.": "1"
        "other": "c"
    },{
        "name": "tom"
        "no.": "1"
        "other": "d"
    },{
        "name": "jack"
        "no.": "2"
        "other": "g"
    }]      
}}
```

---

here is my jsRender template:

```
    <table>      
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Table 1</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>no.</td><td>name</td></tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
    {{for student}}
        <td>{{>no.}}</td>
        <td>{{>name}}</td>
    {{/for}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It will output:

```
no. name
1 tom
2 jacky
1 tom
2 jacky
```

How can i modify my template to  make the output like #table1

Comment: _"first two one is a group, last two one is a group"_ - Do you mean "first two items form a group and the last two items form a group"? [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far? I'd suggest you use a simple `for` loop to iterate over the `people.student` array and each time you encounter a `"no." === "1"` you'll know a new group just began.

Comment: Yes, i mean that. I also get a idea like yours before i write this article, since i am new to javascript and the data need to fit into jsRender template, so i don't know how to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
var yourJSON; // All JSON data
var studentData = yourJSON.people.student; // Student array
var tableIndex = 1; // Index for table name

// Loop to print student data
for (var i = 0, length = studentData.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (studentData[i]['no.'] == '1') {
        if (tableIndex > 1) {
            print('</tbody></table>');
        }
        print('<table>' +
            '<thead>' +
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td>Table ' + tableIndex + '</td>' +
                '</tr>' + 
                '<tr>' +
                    '<td>no.</td>' +
                    '<td>name</td>' +
                '</tr>' + 
            '</thead>' +
            '<tbody>');
        tableIndex++;
    }
    print('<tr><td>' + studentData[i]['no.'] + '</td>');
    print('<td>' + studentData[i]['name'] + '</td></tr>');
}

print('</tbody></table>'); // Closing the last table
```

I don't know how your template engine works so I used the print function to show what is needed to be added in the template.

Comment: But i need separate them to 2 tables, like #table1.

Comment: Made some changes, hope this is what you need.

Comment: I edited my json data, actually there will be two same no. probably ,how about this?

Comment: The script will create a new table for each new object that has the same no.

Comment: on the other hand, in json, how can i separate student to group 1 and group 2

Comment: "student" is an array, you can divide it in multiple arrays using .splice(), more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

But you'll have to rename them so every array has it's unique name in the parent object